# How to attach one SqlCacheDependency to several Cache item?

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(m_connectionString);
m_cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
m_cmd.CommandText = "Select id,name from dbo.instances";
m_cmd.Notification = null;
SqlCacheDependency cacheDepen = new SqlCacheDependency(m_cmd);

using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(m_cmd)) 
{
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     sda.Fill(ds, "instance");
     Cache.Insert("instance", ds.Tables["instance"],cacheDepen);
     Cache.Insert("timeNow", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), cacheDepen);
}
```

I'm create a web application by SqlCacheDependency, Sql Server makes use of Service Broker to notify me when data was updated.
It throw exception "An attempt was made to reference a CacheDependency object from more than one Cache entry" at last two line.
What should I do for the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I just put together a quick console app to test reusing the SqlCacheDependency object and it works fine *if you leave out* `m_cmd.Notification = null;`.

```
namespace CacheDependencyReuse
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products");
        SqlCacheDependency dep = new SqlCacheDependency(cmd);

        // Uncomment this line to get the Exception
        //cmd.Notification = null;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx; Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=xxx; Password=xxx;"))
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(conn.ConnectionString);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet productDataSet = new DataSet();
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(productDataSet);


            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Products",productDataSet,dep);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Now",DateTime.Now,dep);

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

I think if you leave the `Notification` handling to use the default values, then the runtime will sort you out.

Comment: Sorry, it throws the exception again in my code by your advice. I was used SqlDependency which needs Service Broker support, it has some difference from Console Application.